# Streaming paths to main method

Tags: java, java-8

I am writing test that runs a class' main method against each of the zip files in a directory (it takes in the filename as an argument). I have the following:

```
private ArrayList<Path> getZipFiles() throws IOException {
    ArrayList<Path> result = new ArrayList<>();
    Path thisDir = Paths.get("src/test/resources");

    try (DirectoryStream<Path> s = Files.newDirectoryStream(thisDir, "*.zip")){
        s.forEach(filePath -> {
            result.add(filePath);
        });
    }
    return result;
}

@Test
public void test() {
    try {
        ArrayList<Path> p = getZipFiles();
        p.stream().toString().forEach(ValidatorMain::main);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        fail()
    }
}
```

The problem is that `stream().toString()` does not return `String[]` . How can I cast/create a String[] in Java-8 form?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question but I wouldn't transform a `Path` to anything else, unless there is no other way. Certainly not to a string, as the whole point of the `Path` class is to free you from the horrors of string manipulation.

Comment: But it's running a main class, which AFAIK takes in only String[] args.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the Stream API, you should rethink your design. You don’t need to collect the files into an `ArrayList` then:

```
private Stream<Path> getZipFiles() throws IOException {
    Path thisDir = Paths.get("src/test/resources");
    return Files.list(thisDir).filter(p -> p.getFileName().toString().endsWith(".zip"));
}

@Test
public void test() throws IOException {
    try(Stream<Path> s=getZipFiles()) {
        s.map(Object::toString).forEach(ValidatorMain::main);
    }
}
```

Note that it is a very bad idea to catch exceptions in test cases, thus pretending success in the case that the validation actually didn’t even run due to an I/O failure. Letting the test method just throw the exception is much cleaner.

By the way, you don’t need to always use method references nor decompose everything into single methods. So if you stay with your original approach of letting `getZipFiles()` return `List<Path>`, you can also use a lambda expression without the Stream API:

```
private List<Path> getZipFiles() throws IOException {
    Path thisDir = Paths.get("src/test/resources");
    return Files.list(thisDir)
        .filter(p -> p.getFileName().toString().endsWith(".zip"))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
// Alternative:
//    ArrayList<Path> result = new ArrayList<>();
//    try(DirectoryStream<Path> s = Files.newDirectoryStream(thisDir, "*.zip")) {
//        s.forEach(result::add);
//    }
//    return result;
}

@Test
public void test() throws IOException {
    getZipFiles().forEach(p -> ValidatorMain.main(p.toString()));
}
```

Comment: I went with the lambda function as the main method requires String[], not String, and I couldn't figure out how to recast it in the stream.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `map` method in this case like:

```
 p.stream().map(path -> path.toString()).forEach(ValidatorMain::main);
```

Answer (score 0):

`p.stream().toString()` is a `Object::toString` call. It is not a data processing in `stream`.

To do a correct check you need:

```
p.stream().map(Path::toString).allMatch(ValidatorMain::main);
```

i.e. to check that all paths are valid.